Cython dynamic array not converting to Python
I'm working on:

Ubuntu 24.04
Python 3.12
Cython 3.0
cc 13.2.

I have a C module that implements an arbitrary tree and a few constructor functions:
typedef unsigned char byte;
typedef unsigned long ulong;

// ; #region Tree
typedef struct _file {
  ulong length;
  ulong offset;
  byte *data;
} file;

typedef struct _node {
  ulong length;
  byte *value;
  ulong childrenCount;
  struct _node *children;
} node;
// ; #endregion Tree

// ; #region Functions
file read_file(char *file_name);
node process_file(char *file_name);
// ; #endregion Functions

All I have from the C side is a header file and a .so library. The tree is implemented via the children field, which is subject to a malloc. This all works perfectly well on C alone, with no leaks, no SIGSEGV, no fuss.
I'm trying to connect this to Python via Cython. I have the following files:
# cfile.pxd
cdef extern from "file.h":
    ctypedef unsigned char byte;
    ctypedef unsigned short ushort;
    ctypedef unsigned long ulong;

    ctypedef struct file:
        ulong length
        ulong offset
        byte* data

    ctypedef struct node:
        ulong  length
        byte*  value
        ulong  childrenCount
        node*  children

    file read_file(char *file_name)
    node process_file(char *file_name);

and:
# pyfile.pyx
cimport cfile
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free
from libc.string cimport memcpy

cdef class File:
    cdef cfile.file c_struct

    def __cinit__(self, unsigned long length = 0, unsigned long offset = 0, bytes data = None):
        self.c_struct.length = length
        self.c_struct.offset = offset
        self.c_struct.data = <unsigned char *> malloc(length)
        memcpy(self.c_struct.data, <unsigned char *> data, length)

    @property
    def length(self):
        return self.c_struct.length

    @property
    def offset(self):
        return self.c_struct.offset

    @property
    def data(self):
        return list(self.c_struct.data[:self.c_struct.length])


cdef class Node:
    cdef cfile.node c_struct

    def __cinit__(self, unsigned long length, bytearray value, unsigned long childrenCount):
        self.c_struct.length = length
        self.c_struct.value = <unsigned char *> malloc(length)
        memcpy(self.c_struct.value, <unsigned char *> value, length)
        self.c_struct.childrenCount = childrenCount
        self.c_struct.children = NULL

    @property
    def length(self):
        return self.c_struct.length

    @property
    def value(self):
        return bytearray(self.c_struct.value[:self.c_struct.length])

    @property
    def childrenCount(self):
        return self.c_struct.childrenCount

    @property
    def children(self):
        return [Node.from_c_struct(self.c_struct.children[i]) for i in range(self.c_struct.childrenCount)]

    @property
    def from_c_struct(self,):
        cdef Node node = self.__new__(self)
        node.c_struct = self.c_struct
        return node


def read_file(str file_name):
    cdef cfile.file c_data
    c_data = cfile.read_file(file_name.encode('utf-8'))
    file = File.__new__(File)
    file._c_struct = c_data
    return file


def process_file(str file_name):
    cdef cfile.node c_node
    c_node = cfile.process_file(file_name.encode('utf-8'))
    return Node.from_c_struct(c_node)

Finally, I am using the following setup:
# setup.py
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from setuptools.extension import Extension

extensions = [
    Extension(
        name="file",
        sources=["file.pyx"],
        include_dirs=["."],
        libraries=["file"],
        library_dirs=["."],
        runtime_library_dirs=["."],
        extra_objects=["libfile.so"]
    )
]

setup(
    name="file",
    ext_modules=cythonize(extensions),
)

and running python setup.py build_ext --inplace.
ERRORS
I'm getting these:
    @property
    def children(self):
        return [Node.from_c_struct(self.c_struct.children[i]) for i in range(self.c_struct.childrenCount)]
                                                         ^
------------------------------------------------------------

file.pyx:53:57: Cannot convert 'node' to Python object

and
def process_file(str file_name):
    cdef cfile.node c_node
    c_node = cfile.process_file(file_name.encode('utf-8'))
    return Node.from_c_struct(c_node)
                              ^
------------------------------------------------------------

file.pyx:72:30: Cannot convert 'node' to Python object

I believe this is related to the children field, as removing it and all connected logic seems to work.
Question
Any ideas on how to make this work directly with Cython?
I'm looking for a solution that precludes third parties. I found many solutions based on cpython imports or numpy, or even both. I would like to avoid any of that, if possible.
I'm also looking for a solution that does not involve compiling the C code together with the Python code. In order to keep concerns separated, all I want from the C side is the .so.

Why is Node.from_c_struct a property? It sounds like it's supposed to build Node instances from C structs, but it doesn't do that.

@user2357112, I do not know. The docs are… not as comptehensive as I would like them to be, and other examples are rare. The suggested path is always compiling with the C code, which I cannot do. Whatever you could suggest is most welcome and well appreciated.
